# fetching a "href-link" from a JSON file into javascript using the XMLHttpRequest method

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, href

I'm trying to dynamically load data for my cards using javascript and JSON.
**Everything works fine, loading the titles, descriptions & so on.**
Now I'm having this issue where I try to ***dynamically add a separate link*** for each card
(which doesn't seems to work as I thought it would.)

This is my html :

```
  <div class="navbar__container"></div>
```

This is the javascript I used to make it work :

```js
let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('get', 'products.json', true);
http.send();
http.onload = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let products = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let output = "";
        for (let item of products) {
            output += `
            <div class="product">
               <img class="products__img" src="${item.image}" alt="${item.description}">
               <p class="products__title">${item.title}</p>
               <a href="${item.link}" class="products__link">Check it out!</a>
               <p class="products__usedTechnologies">USED TECHNOLOGIES</p>
               <p class="products__description">${item.description}</p>
            </div>
         `;
        }
        document.querySelector(".products").innerHTML = output;
    }
}
```

This is the JSON-File :

```
    {
    "image": "json-images/exampleImg.png",
    "title": "This is an example",
    "description": "html, css, javascript, three.js, webGL, node.js",
    "link": "href=https://bitcoin.org/nl/"
},
```

To make things clear, everything works except the dynamically loading of the link from the json-file, I feel the problem is based on how I call the "href" in the javascript file.

See screenshot of how it looks like:

[image]
The error I get when clicking the link:

[image]

Normally I'm quite fast on how to figure out things like this but this has been something that I can't seem to fix, all help is appreciated

Comment: Looks like you have  href= inside href=

Answer (score 1):

```
      let http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('get', 'products.json', true);
http.send();
http.onload = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        let products = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let output = "";
        for (let item of products) {
            output += `
            <div class="product">
               <img class="products__img" src="${item.image}" alt="${item.description}">
               <p class="products__title">${item.title}</p>
               <a ${item.link} class="products__link">Check it out!</a>
               <p class="products__usedTechnologies">USED TECHNOLOGIES</p>
               <p class="products__description">${item.description}</p>
            </div>
         `;
        }
        document.querySelector(".products").innerHTML = output;
    }
}
```

Hi seems you are making a little mistake by including the href attribute again in your code where you already have it included in the link field of the json. The above corrects the mistake

Comment: pleasure is mine, am glad It helped